# Creating TCP connection from server to android device

Tags: tcp, connection

I'm trying to create tcp connection between server and android device.

I managed to create it when the server (my computer) and the android device were connected to the same router (same local network).

When I connect the device to mobile internet, and try to create tcp connection from the server to the new ip device (which I get by whatismyip.com etc.), it doesn't work..

I guess the problem is wrong IP address, but how can I get the correct ip device? (if it is the problem)

Answer (score 0):

This will be a hard problem to solve, unless the mobile device connected to you first you have no way to know which IP it will have now, and that IP can change a minute later when it switches to another tower or another network altogether.

On top of that you will need to handle firewalls that may be present on the mobile networks that will prevent you from contacting the mobile devices unless they contacted you first.

The normal approach is to have the device poll the server from time to time to get new notifications.

Comment: Yes, that's what I decided to do eventually. Thank you~!!